# Linaro ARM bare metal cross compiler on Windows and libwinpthread-1.dll

Tags: gcc, pthreads, mingw, arm64, linaro

The Windows binary distribution of the Linaro gnu AARCH64 ARM cross compiler (based on mingw) has a dependency on a library **libwinpthread-1.dll**. When I run **.\aarch64-elf-gcc.exe --version** I get a pop-up that says

*The program can't start because libwinpthread-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.*

For the life of me I can't seem to find anything about this library, where to find it, build it, etc. Based on the name it seems obvious that it is some pthread library for windows, but maybe not. The cross compiler is a 32-bit Windows binary for a 64 bit ARM target. The host is 64-bit Windows 10.

Any idea where I can find a 32-bit version of libwinpthread-1.dll?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the tool chain at

https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/6.1-2016.08/aarch64-elf/

seems to not have this problem of a missing dll

It can be found in

gcc-linaro-6.1.1-2016.08-i686-mingw32_aarch64-elf\libexec\gcc\aarch64-elf\6.1.1\libwinpthread-1.dll

Ed